# How to decorate a class and use descriptors to access properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, magic-methods, python-descriptors

I am trying to master (begin ;)) to understand how to properly work with decorators and descriptors on Python 3. I came up with an idea that i´m trying to figure how to code it.

I want to be able to create a class **A** decorated with certain "function" **B** or "class" **B** that allows me to create a instance of **A**, after delaring properties on **A** to be a component of certain type and assigning values on **A** `__init__` magic function. For instance:

**componentized** is certain "function **B**" or "class **B**" that allows me to declarate a class Vector. I declare **x** and **y** to be a *component(float)* like this:

```
@componentized 
class Vector: 
    x = component(float)
    y = component(float) 
    def __init__ (self, x, y): 
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
```

What I have in mind is to be able to this:

```
v = Vector(1,2)
v.x #returns 1
```

But the main goal is that I want do this for every marked **component(float)** property:

```
v.xy #returns a tuple (1,2)
v.xy = (3,4) #assigns to x the value 3 and y the value 4
```

My idea is to create a decorator **@componentized** that overrides the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` magic methods. Sort of this:

```
def componentized(cls):
    class Wrapper(object):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.wrapped = cls(*args)

        def __getattr__(self, name):
            print("Getting :", name)

            if(len(name) == 1):
                return getattr(self.wrapped, name)

            t = []
            for x in name:
                t.append(getattr(self.wrapped, x))

            return tuple(t)

@componentized
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

And it kind of worked, but i don't think I quite understood what happened. Cause when I tried to do an assign and override the `__setattr__` magic method it gets invoked even when I am instantiating the class. Two times in the following example:

```
vector = Vector(1,2)
vector.x = 1
```

How would could I achieve that sort of behavior?

Thanks in advance! If more info is needed don't hesitate to ask!

**EDIT:**

Following @Diego's answer I manage to do this:

```
def componentized(cls):
    class wrappedClass(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            t = cls(*args,**kwargs)
            self.wrappedInstance = t

        def __getattr__(self, item):
            if(len(item) == 1):
                return self.wrappedInstance.__getattribute__(item)
            else:
                return tuple(self.wrappedInstance.__getattribute__(char) for char in item)

        def __setattr__(self, attributeName, value):
            if isinstance(value, tuple):
                for char, val in zip(attributeName, value):
                    self.wrappedInstance.__setattr__(char, val)
            elif isinstance(value, int): #EMPHASIS HERE
                for char in attributeName:
                    self.wrappedInstance.__setattr__(char, value)
            else:
                object.__setattr__(self, attributeName, value)
    return wrappedClass
```

And Having a class **Vector** like this:

```
@componentized 
class Vector:
    def __init__ (self, x, y): 
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
```

It kind of behave like I wanted, but I still have no idea how to achieve:

```
x = component(float)
y = component(float)
```

inside the **Vector** class to somehow subscribe **x** and **y** of type float, so when I do the **#EMPHASIS LINE**(in the line I hardcoded a specific type) on the code I can check whether the value someone is assigning a value to **x** and/or *y* for an instance of **Vector** is of type I defined it with:

```
x = component(float)
```

So I tried this (a component (descriptor) class):

```
class component(object):
    def __init__(self, t, initval=None):
        self.val = initval
        self.type = t

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.val = val
```

To use component like a descriptor, but I couldn't managed to do a workaround to handle the type. I tried to do an array to hold **val** and **type**, but then didn't know how to get it from the decorator **__setattr__** method.

Can you point me into the right direction?

PS: Hope you guys understand what I am trying to do and lend me a hand with it. Thanks in advance

## Solution

Well, using @Diego´s answer (which I will be accepting) and some workarounds to achieve my personal needs I managed to this:

### Decorator (componentized)

```
def componentized(cls):
    class wrappedClass(object):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.wrappedInstance = cls(*args)

        def __getattr__(self, name):
             #Checking if we only request for a single char named value
             #and return the value using getattr() for the wrappedInstance instance
             #If not, then we return a tuple getting every wrappedInstance attribute
            if(len(name) == 1):
                return getattr(self.wrappedInstance, name)
            else:
                return tuple(getattr(self.wrappedInstance, char) for char in name)  

        def __setattr__(self, attributeName, value):
            try:
                #We check if there is not an instance created on the wrappedClass __dict__
                #Meaning we are initializing the class
                if len(self.__dict__) == 0:
                    self.__dict__[attributeName] = value
                elif isinstance(value, tuple): # We get a Tuple assign
                    self.__checkMultipleAssign(attributeName)
                    for char, val in zip(attributeName, value):
                        setattr(self.wrappedInstance, char, val)
                else:
                    #We get a value assign to every component
                    self.__checkMultipleAssign(attributeName)
                    for char in attributeName:
                        setattr(self.wrappedInstance, char, value)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        def __checkMultipleAssign(self, attributeName):
            #With this we avoid assigning multiple values to the same property like this
            # instance.xx = (2,3) => Exception
            for i in range(0,len(attributeName)):
                for j in range(i+1,len(attributeName)):
                    if attributeName[i] == attributeName[j]:
                        raise Exception("Multiple component assignment not allowed")
    return wrappedClass
```

### component (descriptor class)

```
class component(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.type = t #We store the type
        self.value = None #We set an initial value to None

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.value #Return the value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        try:
            #We check whether the type of the component is diferent to the assigned value type and raise an exeption
            if self.type != type(value):
                raise Exception("Type \"{}\" do not match \"{}\".\n\t--Assignation never happened".format(type(value), self.type))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            #If the type match we set the value
            self.value = value
```

(The code comments are self explanatories)

With this design I can achieve what I wanted (explained above)
Thanks you all for your help.

Comment: Assigning objects to instance attributes or changing them is an ordinary task which any instance supports by default. Even for a practice it's better to do something more specific. Also If you want to manage the instance creation (changing their attributes, assigning new attributes, etc.)you'd better look at the `metaclass`es.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thing there is an easiest way to achive the behavior : overloading `__getattr__`and `__setattr__` functions.

#### Getting vector.xy :

```
class Vector:
    ...

    def __getattr__(self, item):
         return tuple(object.__getattribute__(self, char) for char in item)
```

The `__getattr__` function is called only when "normal" ways of accessing an atribute fails, as stated in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=setattr#object.__getattr__).
So, when python doesn't find `vector.xy`, the `__getattr__`method is called and we return a tuple of every value (ie. x and y).
We use `object.__getattribute__` to avoid infinite recurtion.

#### Setting vector.abc :

```
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):

        if isinstance(value, tuple) and len(key) == len(value):
            for char, val in zip(key, value):
                object.__setattr__(self, char, val)

        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
```

The `__setattr__` method is always called unlike `__getattr__`, so we set each value separately only when the item we want to set is of the same lenght as the tuple of value.

```
>>> vector = Vector(4, 2)
>>> vector.x
4
>>> vector.xy 
(4, 2)
>>> vector.xyz = 1, 2, 3
>>> vector.xyxyxyzzz
(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

The only drawback is that if you really want to asign a tuple like (suppose you have an attribute called `size`):

```
vector.size = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Then s, i, z and e will by assigned separately, and that's obviously not what you want !

Comment: Thanks @Diego, Well, the drawback you mentioned doesn't matter to me, i will only use one char named attributes. This is a great approach. But, How would you do that from a decorator function or class?. I mean, I want the decorator class or function `componentized` (I don't know if it should be a class or a function) sort of give that functionality to the class Vector (or whatever class I'd give it to), and use something like `component(float)` to *"flag"* every and only the attributes  I want to behave (and the given type) with the overriden solution you mentioned. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can just make your Vector class inherite a "abstract" class with the overridden `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`ad I've done.

Then you can add some functionalities like a list of there "special" attributes to better fit the setattr...

I can edit my answer to make such a class if you think it's a god idea.

Comment: I don't think decorators are the best choice here

Comment: I edited my question with what you suggested and tried to do what the other thing but couldn't get it done!. PS: @Diego, I don't want `Vector` or any other class I would want this behavior to inherits from an abstract class. I want to decorate it!

Comment: I don't understant why you absolutly want decorators to do this job... it's really hard to achive this behavior this way

On problem you must keep in mind : actually your component value will be the same for all instances of your classes...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've done something similar by *abusing* `__slots__`. I created an Abstract Base Class which read the subclass's slots and then used that for pickling (with `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`). You could do something similar with get-set-attr but you will still need to muck about with the class's actual attr's vs the ones you want to use as get/set properties.

---

*Previous answer:*

Why not just use the [`@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)? See the third example in the docs. You would apply it by first changing the attr names to something different and *private* (like `_x`) and then use the actual name `x` as the property.

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def xy(self):
        return (self._x, self._y)  # returns a tuple

    @xy.setter
    def xy(self, value):
        self._x, self._y = value  # splits out `value` to _x and _y
```

And if you want this to happen with every attr automatically, then you will need to use a metaclass, as @kasramvd commented. If you don't have many such different classes where you want to do this or many properties, may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I thought of this, but I don´t want to define for every combination cause I don´t know them before hand! I just have `x` and `y` and/or `z`, `r`, `g`, `b`, etc.

Comment: Yup, the workaround for the combos was what @Diego has put in their answer, with `__setattr__`.